# Displaying content based on the date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, date

If I need to use the .toDateString() method to display the dates, whats the best way to go about it?

For example: lets say if its between the 1st and 7th of the month the message will Read "x" and everything else is "y"

Thanks very much in advance, working with dates sucks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: If this question is part of an assignment [(as it seems to be)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735363/displaying-content-based-on-the-date-in-javascript#comment25854962_17735419). It is a best practice to disclose this in the question body. That way people won't just give you the answer but rather help you on your own path to finding a solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `.toDateString()` method, that means you are the proud owner of a `Date()` object! This object has many other helpful helper functions. One of them might be of interest to you. It's the [`getDate()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate).

The `getDate()` function will return an integer between 1 and 31. So you'll be able to simply look at the value that is returned and act accordingly.

A **very** simple example :

```
var d = new Date();

switch( d.getDate() ){
  case 1:
  case 7:
    // behavior for days that are the 1st or 7th of the month
    break;
  default:
    // behavior for any day that is not the 1st of 7th of the month
}
```

Reference -

- [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate)

Comment: I have to use the .todatestring() method to satisfy this assignments requirements, it sucks because I already have a good code for this but nothing that uses that method.

Comment: Thanks alot for this answer though, I get what you're saying! Learning javascript has been a breeze until we got to the dates haha.

Comment: @ColbyBradbury You need to use the method to *display* the date, or need to use it for everything about dates? Can you use the var as a `Date` for your `if/else` logic & then parse to a string for displaying it?

Answer (score 0):

In general I would recommend using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It's the best date/time library for javascript. See if it has what you want. Otherwise as far as your problem of showing the date a different way if it's the 1st of the month vs the 21st of the month I would say just use moment's moment().date() function which returns the date of the month.

cheers

Comment: Depending on the situation, a plugin might be overkill. But yea - moment is one of the good ones...

Comment: The thing is I have to use the ".toDateString" methoud to satisfy this assignments requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you can **only** use the `toDateString()` to deal with dates, you'll have to do some string parsing to extract the data you desire...

The `toDateString()` returns a string similar to this: `"Fri Jul 19 2013"`.
What you could do, is split that value by the space character:

```
var date_obj = new Date();
var date_string = date_obj.toDateString();
var date_parts = date_string.split(" ");
```

You'll now have an array that looks like this: `["Fri", "Jul", "19", "2013"]`

All you'll have to do from here is extract the third element at index 2 to get the same output as `getDate()` (which returns exactly what you're looking for).